# Versionado en VS2013 (Error: No encuentra el ensamblado)

Tags: visual-studio

Tenemos em VS 2013, una solución con unos 50 proyectos (2 exe + 48 DLL).
Ahora queremos que la versión de todos los ensamblados se incremente en cada compilación.
Para ello, hemos creado un archivo en uno de los ejecutables con las linieas:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.50.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.50.*")]
```

y hemos añadido este archivo (como vínculo) a todos los otros proyectos (modificando sus respectivos AssemblyInfo.cs a los que les hemos eliminado estas dos líneas)
Además, usamos la extensión Funnel para cargar sólo aquellos proyectos en los que estamos trabajando en un determinado momento.

Pero desde que hemos hecho este cambio, nos vemos obligados a recompilar TODO cada vez que hacemos un cambio (por pequeño que sea) por que saltan errores:

> HRESULT: 0x80131040. Información adicional: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Mbm, Version=2.50.6618.22205, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1915d34d2fd1fdcf' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado.

Entendemos el error, pero no encontramos la forma de que no sea necesario recompilar todo cada vez. Hemos limpiado la solución y recompilado. Y nada.